# Sharded Lists in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In one of my App Engine applications, I need to compile a list of keys for all the entities of a kind, and put them into a list. I used to just run a query over the kind, but it does not scale at all, and I am running into heap errors. I have considered using a sharded list of keys to alieveiate this problem, adding and removing the keys as I update the dataset, but I have run into a few problems getting it to work.

- Are sharded lists possible in app engine?
- Is there a better way to remove objects from a sharded list than to search every shard?
- Is there a better way to get all of the keys of a kind?

Comment: It's really hard to answer this based on the information provided. Can you explain what you're actually trying to achieve? Then we can more easily suggest ways to do it .

Comment: The user needs to get a list of all of keys for entities of a certain kind. They currently get it through an XML file that just has all of the keys, but it is very inefficient because the query is so slow.

Comment: What do they need that list for? If you really need to send them a list of all the keys, there's not going to be anyway to get around the need to retrieve all the keys.

Answer (score 0):

That you're running out of memory suggest that you either aren't querying for keys only, or that you have a lot of that kind of entity. Either way, you probably have too many to show at once, so I assume you'll be doing some form of paging.

This is the ideal use case for cursors. Issue the query, read a page worth of keys (or the entire entity), render it in HTML, and ask the query for a cursor. Save the cursor. When the user pages, reissue the same query, and tell it to start at the saved cursor. Cursors aren't index dependent, so deleting any of the entities that you've already obtained from the query won't mess things up. And if the user loses interest after one page, you don't pay the hit you would for reading the entire list of keys.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries.html#Query_Cursors